# Finding through a joins table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

So I have a Product, product_tags joins table, and Tags. I would like to find all products with a specific tag name using Product.find. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post code, but I presume this is your setup:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_tags
   has_many :tags, :through => :product_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_tags
   has_many :products, :through => :product_tags
end

class ProductTag < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   belongs_to :tag
end
```

Then you can find all the products with a given tag name, e.g. "cool_product" as follows:

```
cool_tag = Tag.find_by_name("cool_product")
cool_tag.products # => list of all products
```

For reference and study, I highly recommend the read through the entire doc page on [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). The association methods are some of the most underappreciated features of Active Record.

Comment: Thanks. I need to use the find method, however, because I'm writing a search method that deals with a dynamic array of arguments. I found a solution, which was just throwing ":include => :tags" at the end of my find arguments.

Comment: The find method on what object? Post some code please, if you want more detail. It's preferable to use Arel's .include or .joins or custom scopes these days than to add :include => ... options.